# C# wpf how to repaint canvas components

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, paint

I'm new with C# programming, I always used Java. I'm trying to make a very simple version of a jumper (such as Doodle Jump) on Visual Studio and I created a WPF project. I need to know the best and the most common way to repaint the object on a canvas (like the player and the platforms, that are all rectangles), so that the objects keep to be updated (for example when I move the player etc.). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596(v=vs.110).aspx). One of the wonderful things about WPF is that you usually don't have to worry about the animation clock or repainting the screen when things change. To move something around the screen, like a rectangle, all you have to do is attach a transformation to it, then update the properties of the transformation. WPF's background rendering thread will automatically take care of the screen update. That article should get you started. Also check out [Storyboards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx) to do more elaborate animations.

Comment: There's only one thing. In my simple game I'm supposed to make a rectangle jump and move, with gravity and all that stuff. Since it's a timed action, how can I move it? I mean, in Java, I created a Thread and every certain time I called the method to move the player. How can I do that in C#with WPF? Thanks.

Comment: There are also very elaborate timed animations available in WPF. Check out Storyboards. I'll add a link above.